# Is it safe to use fopen to perform a cURL with file upload?

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, dropbox-api

I currently have an upload form, which sends the file to Dropbox, through its API. The .php that receives the file to after performing a cURL is as follows:

```
$localFile = $_FILES["file_key"]['tmp_name'];
$fp = fopen($localFile, 'r');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "authorization: Bearer MY-TOKEN",
    "content-type: application/octet-stream",
    "dropbox-api-arg: {\"path\": \"/tmp/a.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}"
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 86400); // 1 Day Timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localFile));
curl_exec ($ch);
```

This works perfectly, but I was troubled about the `fopen` in the second line. Is a bad practice use this? Even though "read-only" mode, can I receive a malicious file and have my system broken?

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly safe. PHP is reading it as pure data, it doesn't try to execute it. `curl` will simply pass it through to the DropBox API. At that point it's DropBox's problem (and it would be quite surprising if they executed code that users upload, unless they have a serious security flaw).

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is safe if you use read only mode, since the file is not being executed, the contents are just being read.

Answer (score 0):

it's the correct way to do it if you're on linux or MacOS* or *BSD and don't care about windows-compatibility, but still i want to nicpick on your code:

if you ever write any code that may run on windows, make a habit of using fopen mode `rb` instead of `r`, because fopen `r` mode on windows may corrupt binary data (and going by your `octet-stream` header, it's binary data) and linux/macos/*BSD all treat `r` and `rb` mode the same way, so make it

```
$fp = fopen($localFile, 'rb');
```

and this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "authorization: Bearer MY-TOKEN",
    "content-type: application/octet-stream",
    "dropbox-api-arg: {\"path\": \"/tmp/a.txt\",\"mode\": \"add\",\"autorename\": true,\"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}"
));
```

should actually read

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "authorization: Bearer MY-TOKEN",
    "content-type: application/octet-stream",
    "dropbox-api-arg: " . json_encode(array(
        'path' => '/tmp/a.txt',
        'mode' => 'add',
        'autorename' => true,
        'mute' => false,
        'strict_conflict' => false,
    ))
));
```

it's just more readable, more maintainable, and easier to modify that way. although i must say putting this data as a HTTP HEADER was a bad design decision on Dropbox's part, there's characters that are illegal in HTTP headers that are perfectly legal in filenames by most filesystem standards, meaning i suspect it's possible to craft a valid json containing a valid filename which can't be http-header-encoded.. they should have used multipart/form-data instead, and just put the file and the json as 2 sepatare form variables, imo.